# Differences in instantiating buffered writers

Tags: java, io

I want to instantiate a buffered writer for writing to a socket outputstream.

```
    String cs = "UTF-8";
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

    Writer writer1 = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(out, cs));

    Writer writer2 = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new BufferedOutputStream(out), cs);

    Writer writer3 = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(out), cs));
```

Is there any non-obvious difference in between the first and second version? Which one is preferred for writing to a socket? Is the third version a bit "overkill"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Third one is overkill.

First one is preferred, because it buffers the data before sending it through the text-to-byte encoder, which performs better when done in blocks vs. one character at a time.

The javadoc of [`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) even says so:

> For top efficiency, consider wrapping an OutputStreamWriter within a BufferedWriter so as to avoid frequent converter invocations. For example:
>
> ```
> Writer out
>   = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
> ```